# snort installation error on centos 6.5

Tags: centos, snort

```
[root@localhost ~]# service snortd start
Starting snort: /usr/sbin/snort: error while loading shared libraries: libdnet.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[FAILED]
```

But libdnet is installed:

```
root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa libdnet
libdnet-1.11-1.2.el6.rf.x86_64
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem using snort-2.9.6.2-1.centos6.x86_64.rpm downloaded from snort.org.

yum install snort-2.9.6.2-1.centos6.x86_64.rpm would not work because it needed version 1.11-1.2.el6 and the current version is 1.12-6.el6 so I had to download the rpm and from http://pkgs.repoforge.org/libdnet. After installing that my snort would install.

That aside I see you are already using the right version but it still doesn't work. So try this

```
# find / -name 'libdnet*'
/usr/lib64/libdnet.so.1.0.1
/usr/lib64/libdnet.so.1
# cd /usr/lib64
# ln -s libdnet.so.1.0.1 libdnet.1
```

Snort should now start assuming everything else such as the conf files are set up ok